# One form with two submit buttons and different actions for each button

Tags: php, forms

I have spent several hours trying to find a solution to my issue, but just can't seem to find the proper solution.  Thanks in advance for your assistance!

I have ONE html form with:

```
<form id="columnarForm"  action="formindb_hoh_1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" />
```

I would like to have TWO submit buttons:

```
<input type="image" name="camper" value="camper" src="../images/apps/camperBtn.png" class="submit_button" />
<input type="image" name="medical" value="medical" src="../images/apps/medicalBtn.png"class="submit_button" />
```

I would like the first submit button to have the action of formindb_hoh_1.php when clicked and the second submit button to have the action of formindb_hoh_2.php, but am unsure how to make one button have one action and have the other button has a different action.

Comment: use javascript submission

Comment: @Nick: as Arun Killu pointed out, are you ok with using some Javascript?

Comment: @ArunKillu, I would prefer not using javascript if I don't have to.  I'm worried about those who have javascript blocked...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Refer this :

[Multiple submit buttons php different actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691653/multiple-submit-buttons-php-different-actions)

Put this script in your page :

```
<script>
    function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('columnarForm').action = action;
        document.getElementById('columnarForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Modify your input code :

```
<input type="image" name="camper" onclick="submitForm('formindb_hoh_1.php')" value="camper" src="../images/apps/camperBtn.png" class="submit_button" />
<input type="image" name="medical" onclick="submitForm('formindb_hoh_2.php')" value="medical" src="../images/apps/medicalBtn.png"class="submit_button" />
```

Comment: The OP wants to post to a different script entirely.

Comment: And make sure you close your form  with </form>

Answer (score 102):

No JS, use HTML5.

Change the submit buttons to use new HMTL5 button attribute **formaction**:

```
<button type="submit" name="camper" formaction="formindb_hoh_1.php">Camper</button>
<button type="submit" name="camper" formaction="formindb_hoh_2.php">Medical</button>
```

Reference: http://devdocs.io/html/element/button

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Just tested it, and works perfectly! Any words on browser / device compatibility?

Comment: I wonder how this interacts with ASP.NET MVC forms, since the form action is specified on the form itself rather than individual buttons.

Comment: <button> action override action from <form> tag and effect depends on browser itself not backend.

Comment: Not working in IE up to version 9. Necessary to place message on your site: `Update your browser.`

Comment: Damn that looked so nice but compatibility looks like it would be a pain in the wild. IE 10 only :( Mind you IE is almost gone :) But Firefox looks like a real problem only supported from version 4 onwards (mind you usage stats are all over the place). Would love to use this but think I will go JS and then suffer when JS is turned off.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got my answer after spending more than an hour. I tried a various method like switch case, jquery, and JavaScript. But I only used HTML5 `formaction` tag and now my form two submit button working at two location.

Code :

```html
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Pay Now" name="submit"  style="width: 100%; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #fff; border: none;padding:  10px;" formaction="example.php">

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" style="width: 100%; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #fff; border: none;padding: 10px; margin-top: 15px;" formaction="mail.php"> Button</buttton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. but the thing is the first button function is in JS while the other is using PHP.

```
$('#add-bookingid').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
calculateDistance();
});
```

You see $('#add-bookingid').submit so both buttons have same button type as submit.

[Main Purpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEDGd.png)

[Button# 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VozRb.png)

[Button# 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc6ee.png)