# Two buttons into same form

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a form and this is its structure:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="script.php">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" >
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST))
    $options = array();
    $options[] = "";
    // here I use the value input in "name" text input, 
    // so I need to get it from the form
    for ($i=0;$i<=count($buscar)-1;$i++) {
        $options[] = "<option value='{$i}'>{$dato}</option>";
    }
    echo '<select class="" id="articles" size="1" name="articles">';
    echo implode("\n", $options);
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

Is there any way to tell the first submit to let the php be executed (because it creates a select item)? 
Then, when the select is selected, click on the second submit and send the complete form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [One form with two submit buttons and different actions for each button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765170/one-form-with-two-submit-buttons-and-different-actions-for-each-button)

Comment: @ctwheels It is not a duplicate of this! :P

Comment: @PraveenKumar My apologies, too much coding for today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do in two ways:

1. Different Naming:

   ```
   <input type="submit" name="sub1" />
   <input type="submit" name="sub2" />
   ```

   And you can check it using:

   ```
   isset($_REQUEST["sub1"])
   isset($_REQUEST["sub2"])
   ```
2. Passing Value:

   ```
   <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit Here" />
   <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit There" />
   ```

   And you can check it using:

   ```
   ($_REQUEST["sub"] == "Submit Here")
   ($_REQUEST["sub"] == "Submit There")
   ```