# PHP - Send a GET Parameter by POST with formvalue

Tags: php, forms, post, get

i have a problem, i will send a POST with PHP but i will
send a GET Parameter with the form value:

```
 <form action="/Eventsuche/" method="post">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input id="Headsucheort" name="Headsucheort" type="text" value="" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button type="submit" name="Submit" id="Headsuchestart" value="Headsuchestart">»</button>
                </td> 
              </tr>
```

So, on submit he bring me to /Eventsuche/ but i would like to
go here: /Eventsuche/Value of Headsucheort

Thanks! :)

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. It's like saying "I want to take an airplane by boat". They're two different methods. I don't know what you mean by "Send a GET parameter by POST".

Comment: change `action`-attribute with javascript before submit.

Comment: then put get into method...??

Comment: Ah, I get it. You want to change the `action` attribute based on the value of `Headsucheort`. As @u_mulder says, change the `action` attribute with JS on submit. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10691688/259457) for a hint of how to change the action before submit.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='/Eventsuche/' + document.getElementById('Headsucheort').value">»</button>
```

Didn't test but

Answer (score 0):

If you really **must** do it in PHP, add this to Eventsuch:

```
if ( isset($_POST['Headsucheort']) ) {
    header('location:http://www.your-url.com/Eventsuche/'.$_POST['Headsucheort']);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to the that.
first:
you can add your variable to the end of your action value such as: `action="Eventsuche?var=somevalue"`

and second one would be:
as a hidden input and even tho it is hidden, php will capture it on submit as in:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myvar_name" value="my_var_value" />
```

i think this should do it.