# two submit button inside one form in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

hi i want to have two submit button in one form in code igniter. is it possible? i want to make two buttons which will do the same thing, add data into the database, the only difference of the buttons is on which page they will redirect.

here is my codes,

```
<?php

  echo form_open('EmpFamilyInfo/add_childinfo/'.$this->uri->segment(3));


?>
// some textboxex,
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class = 'col-md-6 col-sm-offset-6'>
        <button class="btn btn-info fa fa-save" type="submit">&nbsp Save</button>
        <a href = '<?php echo base_url().'EmpFamilyInfo/other_childinfo/'.$this->uri->segment(3); ?>' class = 'btn btn-primary fa fa-save' >&nbsp Add Another</a>
        <a href = '<?php echo base_url().'EmpFamilyInfo/parentsinfo_father/'.$this->uri->segment(3); ?>' class = 'btn btn-danger fa fa-arrow-circle-right'>&nbsp Skip</a>


     <?php

      echo form_close();
    ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

i have made this code which the first link `echo form_open('EmpFamilyInfo/add_childinfo/'.$this->uri->segment(3));` what i wanted this to do is

```
public function other_childinfo(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('NAME',   'Name of Child' ,'trim|required|max_length[100]');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){

        $this->child_info();
    }else{

        if($query = $this->EmpFamilyInfo_Model->insert_childinfo()){

            redirect('EmpFamilyInfo/child_info/'.$this->uri->segment(3));

        }else{

            $this->child_info();
        }
    }   
}
```

but the error is,that it does not have post data. how can i make this link a submit button but it will go to different function or how can i make it have the post data?

Comment: You code having `two anchor tag` instead two submit button!!

Comment: yes. i know. i want one of it to work as submit button.

Comment: imo - give the submit buttons different names then check which was actually used in the controller and redirect as required? No javascript needed.

Answer (score 0):

this question ahs been answered already on this site, so this response is not mine, just quoting for you:
This uses javascript so keep in mind users who have this disabled will not be able to use this solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('form1').action = action;
        document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    }
</script>
```

...

```
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm('page1.php')" value="submit 1" />
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm('page2.php')" value="submit 2" />
```

Comment: its not working. is that one for code igniter? can i have the link ?

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner :), here is the link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691653/multiple-submit-buttons-php-different-actions